# Is it possible to use let-binding for setting keys?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, let-binding

in LaTeX mode `C-cC-f` calls the `tex-file` function. I performed a litte tweak to that function and I wrote a `tex-file-mod` function.
Now I'd like to call the `tex-file-mode` with the same key-binding during some scripts of mine and to restore the default behaviour when I exit these scripts.

Is there a way to do that using a `let-binding` way?

I hope I've been enough clear in my question.

EDIT. I tried, on a Drew's hint, this:

```el
(let (latex-mode-map)
     (define-key latex-mode-map "\C-c\C-f" 'tex-file-mod))
```

But it doesn't restore the default key-binding at the script exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let-bind the keymap variable (presumably `tex-file-mode-map`) to a new keymap:

```el
(let ((tex-file-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap)))
  ...)
```

Its value before binding it is restored after the `let`. After binding it, and within the body of the `let`, assign whatever different bindings you want.

Be aware, however, that, any other changes to the map (e.g. by a user or by other code) during the duration of that `let` will be lost when the `let` is finished.

If you want to start with the current bindings, you need to make a copy, so that your changes don't affect the original keymap:

```el
(let ((tex-file-mode-map (copy-keymap tex-file-mode-map)))
  ...)
```

---

Another approach is to use `unwind-protect`. Save the current bindings for the keys you want to change, then change them, then have the cleanup part of the `unwind-protect` restore them.

Comment: let-bind the keymap variable doesn't work for me. I setted the key with `(define-key latex-mode-map "\C-c\C-f" 'tex-file-mod))` and `(let (latex-mod-map) ...)` but the at the script exit the default key-binding is not restored. Where's my mistake?

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Your example sets `latex-mode-map` to `nil`. See the Emacs Manual node on [Local Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html) for a description of the syntax of `let`.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I suspect that you wanted to copy the original keymap, see my edit.

Comment: I'm actually surprised that let-binding a copy of the keymap (or a sparse keymap) works at all. I think the keymap symbol is not looked up unless the mode is (re)defined (for minor mode) or the mode command is (re)run (for major modes).

Answer (score 3):

[This was going to be a comment to @Drew's answer, but the code will not be rendered correctly.]

I gave this a try and wrote a macro using unwind-protect.

```
(defmacro with-keybinding (map key command &rest body)
  `(let* ((map ,map)
          (key ,key)
          (newcommand ,command)
          (prevbinding (lookup-key map key)))
     (unwind-protect
         (progn
           (define-key map key newcommand)
           ,@body)
       (define-key map key prevbinding))))
```

[Small warning : the macro written above is "not hygienic".]

I tested with :

```
(with-keybinding LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-c") 'ignore
                 (recursive-edit))
```

and checked that `C-c C-c` did nothing, and then did something again after exiting recursive-edit with `C-M-c`.

It might be nice to add a suitable generalized variable so that letf would do this work for us.